# Replacing site-title with a picture in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Every time I try to replace the site-title with a banner image, the formatting messes up and goes wonky. Usually all the links that should be aligned at the bottom of the header float up to the top and get messed up, has anyone encountered this before and know how to fix it?

Here is the header I am using:

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("FantasiTrade", "Index", "Home")</p>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <section id="login">
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </section>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Browse Units", "", new { area = "", controller = "Units"})</li>
                    @{ if (User.Identity.Name != null) { if (User.Identity.Name != ""){
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sell Unit", "Create", new { area = "", controller = "ActiveTrades" })</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Your Profile", "profile", new { user = User.Identity.Name, area = "", controller = "ActiveTrades"})</li>}}}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I want the "menu" list of links to stay aligned at the bottom of the header rather than floating to the top when I replace:

```
<p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("FantasiTrade", "Index", "Home")</p>
```

With:

```
<img src = "mybanner.jpg" />
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me out!

CSS as requested, I THINK these are the relevant parts, the actual file is massive, let me know if you want to see it all:

```
/* site title
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-title {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Medium", Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
    background: none;
    color: #000000;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* login
----------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    display: block;
    font-size: .85em;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

    #login a {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 2px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #login a.username {
        background: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #login ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #login li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
    }


/* menu
----------------------------------------------------------*/
ul#menu {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

    ul#menu li {
        display: inline;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

        ul#menu li a {
            background: none;
            color: #999;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul#menu li a:hover {
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with mvc. It's got something to do with your css. So if you want help, you'll have to paste your css here.

Comment: You're missing the closing `"` for the `src=""` attribute.

Comment: @rudeovskizebear agreed, kgst: please post your rendered markup and CSS, not your Razor source.

Comment: well I am using the default CSS for MVC4, I will edit my post to add it.

Answer (score 0):

try    `<img src = "mybanner.jpg" />` it migth also be an  unclosed tag somewhere although your header looks clean apart from unclossed double quotes.

Comment: Sorry the missing " was just in this post, not on the site, but thanks for your response.